# How to escape asterisk character from Easy Redmine rest API Call

Tags: powershell, api, postman, easyredmine

I want to escape asterisk(*) character  from easy Redmine rest API URL.

I am trying to get the result based on given URL.

```
https://moksh.easyredmine.com/issues.xml?limit=100&tracker_id=4&project_id=109&subject=*ALERT* Sophos XG Firewall - Gateway status alert&sort=updated_on:desc
```

I want only those easy redmine issues where query string matches with api issue response.

But it is selecting all records and it is not filtering based on project and subject. I think asterisk is creating the problem. I am using PowerShell and POSTMAN to call the API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `[uri]::EscapeUriString($url)` ?

Comment: We want asterisk (* ) in the subject parameter to be treated as a literal asterisk character, not a reserved asterisk character.
For Example:-  Issue1- subject =*ALERT*  Sophos XG Firewall - Gateway status alert, project_id=109
                              Issue2 – subject = Test Sophos XG Firewall - Gateway status alert, project_id =109
                                Issue3 – subject = RAM Upgrade from 8GB to 12 GB, project_id=109

For above example , API should return issue1 only. But when we use above API URL then we are getting all issues (issue1,issue2,issue3).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://easyredmine.docs.apiary.io/#reference/issues/issues-collection/list-all-issues), the parameters `sort`, `offset`, `limit` and `page` are required.
You're not using `offset` and `page`.

You can [switch to console on the documentation](https://easyredmine.docs.apiary.io/#reference/issues/issues-collection/list-all-issues?console=1), and build an example with your value, which -using your values- leads to `http://moksh.easyredmine.com/issues.xml?sort=updated_on%3Adesc%20&offset=0&limit=100&page=&tracker_id=4&project_id=109&subject=*ALERT*%20Sophos%20XG%20Firewall%20-%20Gateway%20status%20alert`

Comment: We want asterisk (* ) in the subject parameter to be treated as a literal asterisk character, not a reserved asterisk character.
For Example:-     Issue1- subject =*ALERT*  Sophos XG Firewall - Gateway status alert, project_id=109
                              Issue2 – subject = Test Sophos XG Firewall - Gateway status alert, project_id =109
                                Issue3 – subject = RAM Upgrade from 8GB to 12 GB, project_id=109
For above example , API should return issue1 only. But when we use above API URL then we are getting all issues (issue1,issue2,issue3).